# I want to convert this- ['Fri May 29 20:47:53 2020'] datetime format to date format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I have to convert this- 
`['Fri May 29 20:47:53 2020']` `datetime` format to date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

How do I achieve it in Python.

I have tried this-

```
import os
import time
print(time.ctime(max(os.path.getmtime(root) for root,_,_ in os.walk('/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../'))))
```

Which gives a date like `['Fri May 29 20:47:53 2020'] and I have to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD.`

Can I achive this by simply modifying above code or any other way please suggest.

Comment: you used the module `datetime` ? do you want to format it using python or by using the module methods?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes. Question Edited.

Comment: is it okay to use indexing for this?

Comment: Anything is fine

Comment: mayb u should wait for some1 advanced to come and help, im jus really strting out :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

You should start from `os.path.getmtime()` that returns standard timestamp:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getmtime('y1')
1451122262.0
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( os.path.getmtime('y1'))
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 18, 31, 2)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2015-12-26'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime.strptime with the format of the string you used

 
`%a` is for the local shortened day name (if you have full name of day use `%A`)

`%B` is for month name

`%d` is for date

`%H` is for Hour

`%M` is for month

`%S` is for second

`%Y` is for year

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
dat =['Fri May 29 20:47:53 2020']
for i in dat:
    print(datetime.strptime(i,'%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))

Output:
2020-05-29 20:47:53
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this,

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue-

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
dat =['Fri May 29 20:47:53 2020']
for i in dat:
    print(datetime.strptime(i,'%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y').date())
```